# Why float point precision in C has 7 decimal digits of precision?

Tags: floating-point-precision

I searched for this answer but was unable to understand why 7 digits.
I found an answer which stated.

> 23 fraction bits (22-0) of the significand appear in the memory format but the total precision is actually 24 bits since we assume there is a leading 1. This is equivalent to log10(2^24) ≈ 7.225 decimal digits.
>
> Double-precision float has 52 bits in fraction, plus the leading 1 is 53. Therefore a double can hold log10(2^53) ≈ 15.955 decimal digits, not quite 16.

Why is the logarithm being calculated?
Can you explain me the concept?

Comment: Count the number of digits in 2^24.

Comment: log10(10)=1, log10(100)=2, log10(1000)=3 and so on. Notice the relationship between the number of digits of the operand and the value of the log10 function.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Now I understood it, thanks.